# Code working on server give an error when running on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

To recreate code just simply follow [this article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup)

Final code is:

```
'use strict';

// Imports dependencies and set up http server
const
  express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  app = express().use(bodyParser.json()); // creates express http server

// Sets server port and logs message on success
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337, () => console.log('webhook is listening'));

// Creates the endpoint for our webhook 
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {  
 
  let body = req.body;

  // Checks this is an event from a page subscription
  if (body.object === 'page') {

    // Iterates over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
    body.entry.forEach(function(entry) {

      // Gets the message. entry.messaging is an array, but 
      // will only ever contain one message, so we get index 0
      let webhook_event = entry.messaging[0];
      console.log(webhook_event);
    });

    // Returns a '200 OK' response to all requests
    res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
  } else {
    // Returns a '404 Not Found' if event is not from a page subscription
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }

});

app.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {

  // Your verify token. Should be a random string.
  let VERIFY_TOKEN = "<YOUR_VERIFY_TOKEN>"
    
  // Parse the query params
  let mode = req.query['hub.mode'];
  let token = req.query['hub.verify_token'];
  let challenge = req.query['hub.challenge'];
    
  // Checks if a token and mode is in the query string of the request
  if (mode && token) {
  
    // Checks the mode and token sent is correct
    if (mode === 'subscribe' && token === VERIFY_TOKEN) {
      
      // Responds with the challenge token from the request
      console.log('WEBHOOK_VERIFIED');
      res.status(200).send(challenge);
    
    } else {
      // Responds with '403 Forbidden' if verify tokens do not match
      res.sendStatus(403);      
    }
  }
});
```

Get request route is working fine but when I hit post with this request

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "localhost:1337/webhook" -d '{"object": "page", "entry": [{"messaging": [{"message": "TEST_MESSAGE"}]}]}'
```

I get this error despite a json is valid

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

It's quite unexpected for me, this code works on server with same node version installed - 14.7.6

Comment: Do you know specifically what part of this is returning the error? Can you trace it to a specific line?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't

Comment: have you tried logging the body variable?

Comment: It's seems that .use(bodyParser.json() generates an error but I don't know what I need to change

Comment: What happens if you send the request in string form? Like this
`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "localhost:1337/webhook" -d "{\"object\": \"page\", \"entry\": [{\"messaging\": [{\"message\": \"TEST_MESSAGE\"}]}]}"`

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1

Comment: Is it possible the code you are running is different from the above? I can’t reproduce it.

Comment: It's not, I've just checked it to make sure

Comment: What are your node and bodyParser versions? @WylieFowler

Comment: body-parser@1.19.0 and v14.7.0

Comment: Try [this](https://gist.github.com/wylie39/10c361467b88cbc0f443798cde6eb9ef) I rewrote it according to the body-parser docs.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`